# SQL Join on Table with Duplicates, add condition to get unique values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to join Table B to Table A using SQL in order to get Table B's column called "Reservoir".  They both have a unique ID to join on called "Well_ID" but the issue is that Table B has duplicate ids.  Table B has a column called "Qualifier" and another called "CreatedDate".  Qualifier "Dallas" has precedence over qualifier "Houston" and the latest CreatedDate is needed to find the unique Reservoir value.

[image]

Since I'm unsure how to do the condition, all I have is the join statement so far:

```
SELECT a.*
  ,b.[Reservoir] 
  ,b.[CreatedDateTime] 
  ,b.[Qualifier] 
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b on a.Well_ID = b.Well_ID
```

Comment: So how do you choose the name randomly?  Without any logic, it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join the tables and then assign the prefered record a `row_number()` of `1` per well ID and filter for that.

```
SELECT x.well_id,
       x.reservoir
       FROM (SELECT b.well_id,
                    b.reservoir,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY b.well_id
                                       ORDER BY b.qualifier ASC,
                                                b.createddate DESC) r#
                    FROM b
                         INNER JOIN a
                                    ON a.well_id = b.well_id) x
       WHERE x.r# = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Sticky Bit, what if there are other qualifiers besides Houston and Dallas?  And I just want to focus on Houston and Dallas?  How could I alter your Order By b.qualifier ASC to account for that?  thank you

Comment: @DaBears: If you're lucky the order you want matches their lexicographical order as Dallas and Houston do. If you aren't that lucky use a `CASE` statement to assign numbers to them in the order you want: `CASE WHEN b.qualifier = 'First City' THEN 1 WHEN b.qualifier = 'Second City' THEN 2 ... END`. If you only want records from Dallas and Houston add a `WHERE` to the inner `SELECT`: `WHERE b.qualifier IN ('DALLAS', 'HOUSTON')`